# php $_POST[] not working with some of the text box

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of a problem with `$_POST`
Here is my code for my form:

```
<form action="mailto.php" method="post" class="inquiry-form">
    <p>
        <label for="">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="textField" name="fname">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="textField" name="lname">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="textField" name="email">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="textField" name"add">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="textField" name="phoneno">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Message</label>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="message" name="mmsg">
        </textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-inquiry">
    </p>
</form>
```

and here's my code for `mailto.php`.

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["fname"];
    echo  $_POST["lname"];
    echo $_POST["email"];
    echo $_POST["add"];
    echo $_POST["phoneno"];
    echo $_POST["mmsg"];
?>
```

Everything works fine, but I can't get the values of the form `address` field and the `message` field. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Your label elements aren't doing anything, the `for` attribute needs to match the **id** of their target.

Comment: try using id="" instead onf name=""

Comment: @Connor — No. You need the name for form submission.

Comment: Your `textarea` has `name=""` as well as `name="mmsg"`. The browser is probably getting confused about which one you mean, and just going with the first one (which is blank). The [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will highlight issues like that.

Comment: I down voted your question, because it is simple filled with syntax errors. This is not a "free-Auto-Correct" Forum. You could have spotted those errors within 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax error here:

```
<input type="text" class="textField" name"add">
                                         ^ add =
```

Also in your textarea, you define name="":

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="message" name="mmsg"></textarea>
          ^ remove this
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems I failed to check my code properly.

Answer (score 2):

You are having an `empty name attribute` here so the first `name` attribute will be considered and other will be ignored so PHP doesn't pick up your message

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="message" name="mmsg"></textarea>
```

So it should be

```
<textarea id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="message" name="mmsg"></textarea>
```

Also a blank ID here doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2):

```
 <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="message" name="mmsg"></textarea>
```

Remove empty name attribute in textarea , add '=' after name attribute in,

```
 <input type="text" class="textField" name"add">
```

After that you can check total values passed using

```
    var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>
           <label for="">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="textField" name="add">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="mmsg" cols="30" rows="10" class="message" name="mmsg">                 </textarea>
                </p>
```

You missed a few bits, try this!

There was no name for the message, should have been `mmsg`
There was no = in `name"add"`

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected the code. Try this

Corrected code:

```
 <input type="text" class="textField" name = "add"><textarea name="mmsg" id="mmsg" cols="30" rows="10" class="message"></textarea>
```

Thanks
Jibu